# Destructor invocation in C++

Tags: c++, destructor

I have studied that `Destructor` is invoked whenever the object goes out of scope or when the memory allocated to it is de-allocated using the `delete` operator.

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

class point
{
   private:
      int x_coord;
      int y_coord;

   public:
      point()
      {
         x_coord = 0;
         y_coord = 0;
      }

      point(int x, int y)
      {
         x_coord = (x > 79 ? 79 : (x < 0 ? 0 : x));
         y_coord = (y > 79 ? 79 : (y < 0 ? 0 : y));
      }

      ~point()
      {
         cout << "Destructor invoked\n";
      }

      int getx(void)
      {
         return x_coord;
      }

      int gety(void)
      {
         return y_coord;
      }
};

int main()
{
   point p1;
   point p2(20, 80);

   point *p3 = new point;

   cout << "p1.x =  " << p1.getx() << ": p1.y = " << p1.gety()<< "\n";
   cout << "p2.x =  " << p2.getx() << ": p2.y = " << p2.gety()<< "\n";
   cout << "p3->x =  " << p3->getx() << ": p3->y = " << p3->gety()<< "\n";

   point * p4 = &p1;
   delete p4;
   delete p3;

   return 0;

}
```

1. The memory allocated to p1 is de-allocated using `delete p4`. So destructor is invoked
2. `delete p3` invokes the next destructor.
3. p2 goes out of scope and the next destructor is invoked.

I expected destructor to be invoked only 3 times. But i see the destructor invoked 4 times. What is the reason for this? Is there some mistake with respect to my understanding of destructors

Comment: I don't think `delete p4` is right.

Comment: You shouldn't be `delete`ing `p1` since it was allocated on the stack.

Comment: Your example could be shortened significantly if you removed all of the methods but the destructor, the fields, and the code in `main()` that calls those methods. They aren't relevant to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is mistake in the code. You can not `delete p1` (`p4` points to `p1`) as it was not created with `new`. Thus, the program is invoking undefined behavior.

What happens in this particular case is that p1's destructor gets invoked twice: first with `delete`, second time when `p1` goes out of scope. It could be anything else as well (the other likely outcome is crash).

Answer (score 4):

You are destroying `p1` twice, once when `p1` goes out of scope, but also when you invoke `delete p4`, which is just a pointer to `p1`, not to a separate object. Destroying an object twice is undefined behaviour, btw (as is deleting a stack object (see comment)).

Comment: It is not an UB because an object is being destroyed twice, but it is an UB because an address which was not returned by `new` is being passed to `delete`. `p1` is an object on stack and not on freestore.

Answer (score 1):

`p1` was allocated on the stack, so even though you called `delete` on `p4`, delete will be called on the now-unallocated `p1`.

Note that deallocating memory doesn't (necessarily) zero it out. So it is possible for the destructor to be called again and print the message. Or it might blow up. That is why it is critical to ensure that you don't deallocate memory before your last use.

Answer (score 0):

Your destruction of p1 through pointer p4 is invalid and will throw a runtime error if you are compiling with the debug CRT.